# BlockingScheduler Attempted to Start out of Schedule

Tags: python, scheduler, apscheduler

I am using `BlockingScheduler` from `apscheduler` in a `python` script in order to run **two jobs**, one at **10:00AM** and one at **16:30** **Every day for every weekday**.

The scheduler for a very long time run smoothly but suddenly one day it did not run at `10:00` as planned but made an attempt **1.5 hours later**. The script runs from `cmd` on my `local machine` and not in an actual `server` if that helps.

Below follows the code I am using:

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(main_func, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=10, minute=0, end_date='2021-06-30')
scheduler.add_job(main_func, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=16, minute=30, end_date='2021-06-30')
scheduler.start()
```

Any points are welcome to explain this behavior and fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Questions:

1. Is this really all the configuration you have for the scheduler? It does not seem plausible that a job started at 11:30 with the default settings. Are you sure that it didn't start and then take that long to finish?

2. Have you tried turning on debug logging (as per the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#troubleshooting))?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. That's all the configuration. It does not seem realistic that it took 1.5 hours because it usually needs only a minute on average to do the job. I did not have the logs on before but i enabled them after that. Could it be anything thread related, like something killed/paused the thread? Not an expert on processes anyway.

Comment: Threads cannot be killed, or force-paused from the outside. The logs might reveal the cause the next time it happens.